# linear forms are independent

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

how to shows that three linear forms are independent:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
f_1 & : & R^3 & \longrightarrow   & R \\
 & & (x,y,z) & \mapsto & f(x,y,z)=x+2y+\beta. z \\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
f_2 & : & R^3 & \longrightarrow   & R \\
 & & (x,y,z) & \mapsto & f(x,y,z)=2x+4y \\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
f_3 & : & R^3 & \longrightarrow   & R \\
 & & (x,y,z) & \mapsto & f(x,y,z)=ax+(a+1)y. \\
\end{array}$$

This subject is related to that [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061219/dimension-of-the-intersection-of-affine-subspaces?noredirect=1#comment2160164_1061219)

we took a,b,c that different to 1 for f1,2,3 are linear forms
i don't have any idea i need this to complete my answer in that [subject](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061219/dimension-of-the-intersection-of-affine-subspaces?noredirect=1#comment2160164_1061219)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: these are not linear forms if $a$ or $b$ or $c$ is not 0.

Comment: $a,b,c\neq 1$ for $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linear form non zero

Comment: For what are generally said to be "linear forms", mookid's comment applies. Maybe you could state what you define as linear form?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form

Comment: you do not seem to make so much effort here. according to *your* link, $f_{1,2,3}$ are not linear forms.

Comment: i need help not downvote

Comment: i'm not student i m free learner start to learn math form the begining